# Using events of dynamically created buttons to redirect to another page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm trying to call events of dynamically created buttons sending parameters, but when I click nothing happens, just Post Back the page.

```
public void adicionarComanda()
    {
        List<Comanda> lc = ControllerComanda.getComanda();

        foreach (Comanda comanda in lc)
        {
            Button bt = new Button();
            bt.Text = comanda.nome_Pessoa;
            bt.CssClass = "botoes";
            bt.Click += btnNome1_Click;
            bt.CommandArgument = comanda.nome_Pessoa;              

            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            li.Controls.Add(bt);
            ulBotoes.Controls.Add(li);
        }

    }
```

And the Event

```
protected void btnNome1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nomePessoa = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
        Session["currentUser"] = nomePessoa.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Pages/produtosCategoria.aspx");
    }
```

But nothing Happens when I click the button, just PostBack the page. How can I fix this problem?

Thank you guys

Comment: I think your event handler on every buttons lost after every post back. you need to assign handler every time the page posted back

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-render all dynamically generated controls on every postback. I suggest creating a method that generates the these controls then call that method on every postback in `Page_Load`.

Comment: But I don't want to recreate the buttons, I just want to be redirected to another page on button click

Comment: If that's the case, then you can call a client-side script that does the redirection and avoid server-side event. You can use `bt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:redirect(url);");`

Comment: But I also want to define this session : Session["currentUser"] = nomePessoa.ToString(); that is on method. It will work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about maybe passing "currentuser" as a parameter?                                                                          bt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:redirect('~/Mobile/Pages/produtosCategoria.aspx?name=comanda.nome_Pessoa')";

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining click function you can use another approach - **PostBackUrl**.

```
public void adicionarComanda()
{
    List<Comanda> lc = ControllerComanda.getComanda();

    foreach (Comanda comanda in lc)
    {
        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.Text = comanda.nome_Pessoa;
        bt.CssClass = "botoes";
        bt.PostBackUrl = String.Format("~/Mobile/Pages/produtosCategoria.aspx?user={0}", comanda.nome_Pessoa);           

        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.Controls.Add(bt);
        ulBotoes.Controls.Add(li);
    }

}
```

Then in the redirected page you can use **Request.QueryString["user"]** , and use it as required.